# Error: The view 'xx' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations... on logon?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, encoding, razor, controller, authentication

In view logon, log on with.

**User**: admin
**Password**: xxx

I can log in normally.

When you try to:

**User**: tavaresdemelo.adv.br
**Password**: xx

The error is displayed:

> The view 'tavaresdemelo.adv.br' or ITS master was not found or the
>   view engine supports the searched locations. The Following Were
>   searched locations: ~ / Views / account / tavaresdemelo.adv.br.aspx ~
>   / Views / account / tavaresdemelo.adv.br.ascx ~ / Views / Shared /
>   tavaresdemelo.adv.br.aspx ~ / Views / Shared /
>   tavaresdemelo.adv.br.ascx ~ / Views / account /
>   tavaresdemelo.adv.br.cshtml ~ / Views / account /
>   tavaresdemelo.adv.br.vbhtml ~ / Views / Shared /
>   tavaresdemelo.adv.br.cshtml ~ / Views / Shared /
>   tavaresdemelo.adv.br.vbhtml

**Account Controller**

```
public ActionResult LogOn()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LogOn(string userName, string password, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (Membership.ValidateUser(userName, password))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, false);
            if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Usuário ou senha estão inválidos");
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(userName);
}

public ActionResult LogOff()
{
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

**View Logon**

```
@model string
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Login";
}

<div id="login">
    <h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Erro ao tentar efetuar o login.")
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <fieldset class="login">
            <legend>Entre com seu usuário e senha</legend>
            <div class="inline">
                @Html.Label("userName", "Usuário: ")
                @Html.TextBox("userName", Html.Encode(Model))
                @Html.ValidationMessage("userName")
            </div>

            <div class="inline">
                @Html.Label("password", "Senha: ")
                @Html.Password("password")
                @Html.ValidationMessage("password")
            </div>

            <div class="form-buttons">
                <input type="submit" class="button" value="Login" title="Login" />
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This line

```
return View(userName);
```

tells the framework to load a view called userName (or in this case tavaresdemelo.adv.br). That is why you are getting the error that it can't find the view called tavaresdemelo.adv.br.aspx, etc. I *think* what you're trying to do would be

```
return View();
```

or

```
return View("logon");
```

or whatever the name of the view you're trying to reload is.

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

For other instances of this error, `return View("logon")` does not work for me.
I have found out that `return RedirectToAction("View", "Controller")` does solve this issue.